# html: How to split a very large html file, into pieces without breaking formatting

Tags: html, unix

I have a large html file, downloaded from some place. I need to convert it to pdf eventually. Is there a way to split it into several html smaller parts (e.g. kind of a pagination).

(I do not control the part of creating html file, so can do nothing on server side)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would be a tedious manual process to me. Consider `html2pdf` and other similar utilities to convert the entire chunk into a PDF, then doing the pagination using `pdftk`.

If the CSS includes any print style definitions, that might be of use. But generally it's not possible to automate would be my answer.